# Renaming Files Through Script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a few files that are incorrectly named (with the extension added twice to the end).  I was trying to write a bash script that would scan the directory and rename them, but it throws an error of:

> cannot move ‘/var/random/file/file1.avi.mp4’ to ‘{/var/random/file/file1.avi.mp4%.avi.mp4}.mp4’: No such file or directory

I just want to properly rename the file extension, and am not sure where the error comes into play.  For example, the error above, should have a file extension of .mp4.  Below is my script, if someone could assist, I would be in debted...

```
#/bin/sh
for file in $(find /var/random/ -type f -name "*.avi.mp4"); do
  mv "$file" "{$file%.avi.mp4}.mp4"
done
```

Comment: `mv "$file" "${file%.avi.mp4}.mp4"`

Comment: Please see the other answer that I didn't post, it have some important change of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in your variable expansion:

```
"{$file%.avi.mp4}.mp4"
```

should have been:

```
"${file%.avi.mp4}.mp4"
```

However you might want to take a look at `rename` (`perl-rename`)

```
perl-rename 's/[^.]+\.(?=[^.]+$)//' /var/random/*/*.avi.mp4
```

The regex will remove the second to last extension in file names:

```
/path/to/file/foo.bar.baz -> /path/to/file/foo.baz
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -type f -name "*.avi.mp4" -print0 | while read -rd '' filename
do
if [ -e "${filename%.avi.mp4}.mp4" ]
then
  mv --backup "${filename}" "${filename%.avi.mp4}.mp4"
  #doing the backup only if the destination file exists to save space.
else
  mv "${filename}" "${filename%.avi.mp4}.mp4"
fi
done
```

**What happened  here :**

1. We `find` out all the files ending with `.avi.mp4` extension.
2. Since the file can contain newline characters, we make the filenames null terminated using `print0` option of the `find`.
3. This output is piped into while loop where we are ready to parse the files.
4. Setting the delimiter `-d` option of the `read` to null(`''`) command we parse each of the null terminated filenames.
5. Finally we use parameter expansion/substitution to get rid of the `.avi.mp4` at end of each file and append a `.mp4` to each file at the `mv` phase.  See reference 1.

**References :**

1. [Shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)
2. [Move manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mv)
3. [Why use while instead of for?](https://superuser.com/questions/409818/how-do-i-parse-the-output-of-the-find-command-when-filenames-have-spaces-in-them)

Comment: Can you please ellabriate on why you changed the `for x in ...` to a while loop and why `-print0` is used. I think OP might not know why what you are doing is important! +1

Comment: @andlrc : Doing in the moment.

Comment: Strongly recommend `"${filename}"` and `"${filename%.avi.mp4}.mp4"` with double quotes around the names; this works even with `Cute Cat.avi.mp4` whereas omitting the quotes wreaks havoc (or noisy error messages) — especially given the pains you've gone to ensuring your code handles such file names in the `find … | while read …` code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : I was doing a [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) while you were posting the comment. Updated the script :D

Comment: Much improved.  It's a good idea for your reflex shell coding style to write variables inside double quotes, removing them only if there is a need to do so, rather than vice versa.